# How does instagram implements its searchview?

Tags: android, searchview

when we click on Instagram's `SearchView` in its search fragment it seems that the current fragment changes i.e it shows the fragment containing previous searches and it's also the place where we could search for someone.
I have tried implementing this using `setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener` where in my project I have tried transitioning from search fragment to some target activity, but the transition seems to be slow.

**code:**

**SearchFragment**

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
      if (hasFocus) {
          Helper.switchActivity(view.context, CustomerInfoActivity::class.java)
      }
  }
```

**switchActivity**

```
  fun switchActivity(context: Context, targetActivity:Class<out Activity>){
    val intent = Intent(context,targetActivity)
    context.startActivity(intent)

}
```

How do I implement this? what is the best way?